# I am wondering how js fiddle is handling their textareas concerning resizing and their layot

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, textarea

I wonder how the site jsfiddle.net is handling their textareas. When you resize one, the others shrink/gain size. I've been trying to do it regularly with css but when I resize one, the other textarea pops under the first textarea. Something like this.

```
|[   ][   ]|
resize work....
|[     ]   |
[]
```

so the other textarea goes down. The | are ment to be the sides of the homepages and the [] are the textareas.

Comment: You could position all text-areas absolutely, and then only change their `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`right` CSS properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see with Chrome inspector, they are first separated in two columns, with position:absolute. The one on the left with a "left" css property set, and the one on the right with a "right" css property set.

Then each columns have two rows, that use the same method, the other way around (with top and bottom css properties set).

Then javascript comes in. When the handle is dragged, each column or row couple's height or width are changed to give the same sum.

**EDIT :** Here you can see some javascript from jsfiddle.

onDrag_horizontal resizes two rows of a column. It takes the position of the handle h (`var top = (h.getPosition(this.content).y + h.getHeight() / 2) / this.content.getHeight() * 100;`) and then sets the height of the two rows accordingly

```
var onDrag_horizontal = function(h) {
    var windows = h.getParent().getElements('.window');
    var top = (h.getPosition(this.content).y + h.getHeight() / 2) / this.content.getHeight() * 100;
    windows[0].setStyle('height', top + '%');
    windows[1].setStyle('height', 100 - top + '%');
}.bind(this);
```

onDrag_vertical does the same thing, but with the vertical handle, which resizes the two columns

```
var onDrag_vertical = function(h) {
    var left = (h.getPosition(this.content).x + h.getWidth() / 2) / this.content.getWidth() * 100;
    this.columns[0].setStyle('width', left + '%');
    this.columns[1].setStyle('width', 100 - left + '%');
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: The project I'm working on requires 3 text areas, [][] and then the third under these 2. I'm not sure what kind of library js fiddle is using, but I thought I could just either do it with regular javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I'd recommend jQuery. You can use do as I explained for jsfiddle, except you'd start with two rows, and divide your top row in two columns...

Comment: You could easily modify this jqueryui example to have two columns resize simultaneously to have the same sum of width... http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#synchronous-resize

Comment: we use MooTools - and I fully can recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am able to solve it now with your help, I was using the relative position and I should have been using absolute so the textarea doesn't jump down. I am using jQuery's resizable ui because it seems onresize in basic javascript doesn't apply to other elements, just the window.

Basically make the left textarea resizable and add to the event 'resize' that whenever it is resizable, the dimensions of the other textareas change like,

```
$('#rightBox').css('width', totalsize + (ui.originalSize.width - ui.size.width));
$('#rightBox').css('height', totalsize + (ui.originalSize.height- ui.size.height));
```